# Easiest way to modify JSON config file

Tags: json, cmd, jq

I've got files of different sizes (n entries) such as:

```js
{
    "FOO": {
        "myParameters": ["first", "second", "third", "forth", "fifth"]
    },
    "bar": {
        "myParameters": ["first", "third"]
    },
    "BAZQUUX": {
        "myParameters": ["first", "second", "third", "forth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth"]
    }
}
```

and I'd like to modify it like this:

```js
{
    "FOO": {
        "myParameters": ["first", "third"]
    },
    "bar": {
        "myParameters": ["first", "third"]
    },
    "BAZQUUX": {
        "myParameters": ["first", "third"]
    }
}
```

So the *bar* object's property *myParameters* (the array containing two items) should be the template for all remaining objects (*FOO*, *BAZQUUX*, etc.) left, they should adopt the property of *bar*, discarding their existing properties.

Is there a simple way to achieve this via jq?

I need it for a batch script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following `jq` script:

```
<file jq '.bar as $b | .[] |= $b'
```

This assigns the object `bar` to the variable `$b` and replace all elements with this variable.

Comment: I get: _The command ".[]" is either misspelled or could not be found._ That's the main obstacle using jq within cmd.exe. I also tried to cram that line into a For /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a construction, but without success.

Comment: @dabbl0r Use single quote instead of backtick

Comment: It turned out that the variant `<file jq ".bar as $b | .[] |= $b"` is functional for cmd. Thank you very much!